# AngularJS material - set parent div for <md-option>

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angularjs-material, md-select

I'm using AngularJS material 1.1.8. And I have a md-select element with md-option that uses ng-repeat to populate the list items:

```
<body>
    <div>
      <div id="my-select-div" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
         <md-select placeholder="Select Item" class="md-no-underline"
         md-container-class="my-md-select-dropdown">
             <md-option ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items" ng-value="item">
                     <header>{{ item.name }}</header>
             </md-option> 
         </md-select>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When pressing the md-select, Angular creates a new div for the md-options under body element the and not under the div "my-select-div" which is the actual parent of the md-select.

How can I set the parent of the md-option's div to be "my-select-div"?

Thanks.